# Regex for hour, minute and second format HH:MM:SS

Tags: regex

Im trying to implement a Regex for HH:MM:SS, example:

```
07:15:30
```

But I can't get it work

Right now Im using:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Any clue?

Comment: I'm going to reopen this question this time, but in the future, please avoid vague statements such as "I can't get it work" **without an explanation of *in what way something doesn't work***, because it's a classic sign of a question that doesn't contain enough information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
^(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   #  Start of string
(?:                 #  Try to match
([01]?\d|2[0-3]):   #  HH:
([0-5]?\d):         #  MM:
)?                  #  (entire group)
([0-5]?\d)          #  SS
$                   #  End of string
```

Used some expressions from the regex cheat sheet here:

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

**EDIT #1**

```
^(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]\d)$
```

Removed the `?` on the `SS` to make it return false if only 1 digit is entered for seconds.

**EDIT #2**

```
^([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

Changed the `HH` part a little so if the user types just `HH` without the `MM` and `SS`, it returns false.

**EDIT #3**

Thanks to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347895/regex-for-hour-minute-and-second-format-hhmmss/24347898?noredirect=1#comment37645470_24347898) for this expression to add to this list

```
^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)
```

Comment: I need to force 00:00:00 with leading zeros if its the case. Right now is not doing that :(

Comment: You want it to return false if 00:00:00 is typed?

Comment: I mean, the mask should be 00:00:00, so 13:51:10, right now if I type 13:51:1 is valid and it shouldn't.

Comment: Almost there, that part is fixed, but if I just type 33 (without anything else) the regex saying that is correct.

Comment: That is basically because you can say 12, it is like 12 o clock... I noticed this too but let me try to fix it :)

Comment: your second edit matches 59:9:59 should it be `^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)`

Comment: Can you double check now? I think it should be fixed :)

Comment: Actually removed all the `?` to make it more strict ;). Please let me know if my Edited one works

Comment: still you're matching 59 in the hour field

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked it and it worked fine... Check the Edit #2

Comment: Edit #2 still matches 59 in the hour field [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/zH7qE9) you need this pattern `^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)`

Comment: I will add your expression with your credits of course but my expression worked fine when I tested it.

Comment: The noncapturing group syntax `(?:...)` is a Perl extension and not compatible with traditional regex. You can remove the `?:` part and replace `\d` with `[0-9]` if you need this for a traditional tool like `grep`, `sed`, Awk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<hours>(?<=(^|\s))([01]\d|2[0-3])(?=:)):(?<minutes>(?<=:)[0-5]\d(?=:)):(?<seconds>(?<=:)[0-5]\d(?=($|\s)))/
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: The named groups like `?<hours>` are a Perl extension and not part of traditional regex syntax.